# C++ Linked List of Objects

Tags: c++, class, object, linked-list

I have a class whose objects must be added to a linked list. The objects are only created within a non-member function. I have to admit, linked lists make no sense to me at all, and yes, I've read other questions on this forum and still can't figure it out.

How would I go about 1. creating this linked list 2. adding an object to this list each time one is created and 3. be able to delete every node of the list?

This is my class:

```
class ShirtOrder
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const ShirtOrder &rhsObj);

private:
    // the data members below are required (you may change identifiers)
    // there is no need for additional data members
    int orderYear, orderMonth, orderDay;
    char printMethod; // 's', 'i', or 'e'
    string message;
    int mediums; // number of medium shirts ordered
    int larges; // number of large shirts ordered
    int xls; // number of XL shirts ordered
    string shirtColor;
    string inkColor;
    string orderID;
    string region;
    string nameAndEmail;

    ShirtOrder* next; // new for P5

public:
    ShirtOrder(); // default constructor

    ShirtOrder(int orderYear, int orderMonth, int orderDay,
               char printMethod, string message, int mediums, int larges, int xls,
               string shirtColor, string inkColor, string orderID,
               string region, string nameAndEmail,
               ShirtOrder *soPtr = NULL);

    ShirtOrder(const ShirtOrder &otherObj);

    ~ShirtOrder(); // destructor                      // New for P5 (may not be in-line)

    ShirtOrder* getNext() const {return next;}        // New for P5 (may be in-line)

    void setNext(ShirtOrder* soPtr) {next = soPtr;}   // New for P5 (may be in-line)

    double getBlankCost() const;
    double getPrintingCost() const;
    double getTotalCost() const;

    int    getLetterCount() const;
    char   getPrintMethod() const {return printMethod;}
    int    getOrderYear() const {return orderYear;}
    int    getOrderMonth() const {return orderMonth;}
    int    getOrderDay() const {return orderDay;}
    int    getMediums() const {return mediums;}
    int    getLarges() const {return larges;}
    int    getXls() const{return xls;}

    string getShirtColor() const {return shirtColor;}
    string getInkColor() const {return inkColor;}
    string getOrderID() const {return orderID;}
    string getRegion() const {return region;}
    string getNameAndEmail() const {return nameAndEmail;}
    string getMessage() const {return message;}

    void  setOrderYear (int orderYear) {this->orderYear = orderYear;}
    void  setOrderMonth (int orderMonth) {this->orderMonth = orderMonth;}
    void  setOrderDay (int orderDay) {this->orderDay = orderDay;}
    void  setPrintMethod (char printMethod) {this->printMethod = printMethod;}
    void  setMessage (string message) {this->message = message; }
    void  setMediums (int mediums) {this->mediums = mediums;}
    void  setLarges (int larges) {this->larges = larges;}
    void  setXls (int xls) {this->xls = xls;}
    void  setShirtColor (string shirtColor) {this->shirtColor = shirtColor;}
    void  setInkColor (string inkColor) {this->inkColor = inkColor;}
    void  setOrderID (string orderID) {this->orderID = orderID;}
    void  setRegion (string region) {this->region = region;}
    void  setNameAndEmail (string nameAndEmail) {this->nameAndEmail = nameAndEmail;}

};
```

So say an object of this class is created within a non-member function. How do I create a list of such objects, and add each object to the end of the list? Thanks!

Comment: *How do I create a list of such objects* -- `std::list<ShirtOrder>` -- *add each object to the end of the list* -- `std::list<ShirtOrder> myShirts; myShirts.push_back(ShirtOrder());`

Comment: I need it to be a linked list, specifically. Though I thank you for your answer!

Comment: `std::list` is a linked list.  If this is supposed to be some sort of home-made linked list, why obfuscate by making a `ShirtOrder` class?  Create a generic linked list class first, test it, and then use it in your `ShirtOrder` class.

Comment: Do you want to show us the signature of the non-member builder function, or should we make it up?

Comment: To clear up my comment, I need each node in the list to be accessible by the previous node's "next" pointer...

Comment: Problem is that to answer all of your questions requires us to write you a linked list class that works, not just a couple of lines of code here and there.  That's why you should start with just a linked list first that takes any type, not just `ShirtOrder`'s, and attempt to put it together.

Answer (score 0):

In your private field create a `std::lib<dataType> mylist;`

Then you just insert what items you wants. `mylist.insert(whateverItem);`

Does that help?

Comment: By the way, I recommend Qt. It has amazing libraries to make this way easier.